# Keeping apps tamper proof

Tags: swift, xcode, security, tampering

Currently designing an iOS app that has functionality including the transfer of in-game currency to real-world currency. ( within Xcode using swift, it’s a mobile game )

Since this app includes the prospect of real money, I couldn’t help but feel that people would tamper with the game mechanics and take advantage of it.

My current idea of keeping the app tamper proof is to have the user fill in form, where not only would the user input all their relevant information, but in the background include users app data showing all their moves and game history ( there is no break of privacy as the app is only a basic game, they don’t input any private information apart from payment info at the end ).

Is there any MUST HAVES I should include in the code to make sure that the game is tamper-proof, or at least a way in which I can spot tampering? ( I assume there is already threads out there, let me know of them that would be great ).

Thanks

Comment: The only thing you can do to make apps "tamper-proof" is to store all state on the server. Anything else can be circumvented.